# Why am I not getting the text in the XML tag? - python elementtree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, readxml

How do i read the all the text within in the `<context>...</context>` tag? And how about the `<head>...<\head>` tag within the `<context \>` tag?

I've an XML file that looks like this:

```
<corpus lang="english">
    <lexelt item="coach.n">
        <instance id="1">
            <context>I'll buy a train or <head>coach</head> ticket.</context>
        </instance>
        <instance id="2">
            <context>A branch line train took us to Aubagne where a <head>coach</head> picked us up for the journey up to the camp.</context>
        </instance>
    </lexelt>
</corpus>
```

But when i ran my code to read the XML text within the ..., I'm only getting the text until i reach the  tag.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et    
inputfile = "./coach.data"    
root = et.parse(open(inputfile)).getroot()
instances = []

for corpus in root:
    for lexelt in corpus:
      for instance in lexelt:
        instances.append(instance.text)

j=1
for i in instances:
    print "instance " + j
    print "left: " + i
    print "\n"  
    j+=1
```

Now I'm just getting the left side:

```
instance 1
left: I'll buy a train or 

instance 2
left: A branch line train took us to Aubagne where a
```

The output needs also the right side of the context and the head, it should be:

```
instance 1
left: I'll buy a train or 
head: coach
right:   ticket.

instance 2
left: A branch line train took us to Aubagne where a 
head: coach
right:  picked us up for the journey up to the camp.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you have a mistake in your code. `for corpus in root` is not necessary, your root is already `corpus`.

What you probably meant to do was:

```
for lexelt in root:
  for instance in lexelt:
    for context in instance:
      contexts.append(context.text)
```

Now, regarding your question - inside the `for context in instance` block, you can access the other two strings you need:

1. The `head` text can be accessed by accessing `context.find('head').text`
2. The text in the right of your `head` element can be read by accessing `context.find('head').tail`
   According to the [Python etree docs](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#element-objects):

> The `tail` attribute can be used to hold additional data associated with
>   the element. This attribute is usually a string but may be any
>   application-specific object. If the element is created from an XML
>   file the attribute will contain any text found after the element’s end
>   tag and before the next tag.

Comment: you mean my root is already `corpus` or my root is already `context` at the start?

Answer (score 1):

Within ElementTree you will have to consider the tail property of child nodes. Also corpus IS root in your case.

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as et    
    inputfile = "./coach.data"    
    corpus = et.parse(open(inputfile)).getroot()

    def getalltext(elem):
        return elem.text + ''.join([getalltext(child) + child.tail for child in elem])

    instances = []
    for lexelt in corpus:
        for instance in lexelt:
            instances.append(getalltext(instance))


    j=1
    for i in instances:
        print "instance " + j
        print "left: " + i
        print "\n"  
        j+=1
```

Comment: thanks, getalltext(elem) is indeed useful in python's element tree, should suggest to include this recipe in the next elementtree version.